# Block of code as a separate module in Python

Tags: python

Assume I have a list `my_list`, a variable `var`, and a block of code that modifies the list using the variable

```
my_list = ['foo']
var = 'bar'
my_list.append(var)
```

In the actual task I have a lot of variables like `var` and a lot of commands like `append` which modify the list. I want to relegate those commands to another module. In the case at hand I would like to have two modules: `modify.py` which contains the modifying commands

```
my_list.append(var)
```

and `main.py` which defines the list and the variable and somehow uses the code from the `modify.py`

```
my_list = ['foo']
var = 'bar'
import_and_run modify
```

The goal is to make the main file more readable. Modifying commands in my case can be nicely grouped and would really be good as separate modules. However, I am only aware of the practice when one imports a function from a module, not a block of code. I do not want to make the whole `modify.py` module a function because

1) I don't want to pass all the arguments needed. Rather, I want `modify.py` to directly have access to `main.py` name space.

2) code in `modify.py` is not really a function. It runs only once. Also, I do not the whole module to be a body of a function, that just does not feel right.

How do I achieve that? Or the whole attitude is wrong?

Comment: The first Python app I ever wrote consisted of modules that imported modules whose code ran immediately on import.  The lesson I learned was to use functions :)

Comment: It does not feel right, to have a module access the namespace of another module. Just define functions, never use global variables, use function arguments.

Comment: We could better discuss whether one or the other approach would be helpful would we see the code. Can you show it here or share in a Gist?

Comment: I'll have to reconsider using functions. @flaschbier sry, I don't think I can share the code. But basically I create a presentation using python-pptx package. After making a presentation object `prs` I have to make and fill a lot of slide objects. Adding slide is modifying a presentation object `slide=prs.slide.add_slide()`. I am not sure how to make this a function defined in a separate module. Moreover, different slides use a lot of common variables which I do not want to define in each submodule or pass as arguments, hm.

Comment: consider combining the common variables (the format frame) into a `dict` and passing that

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make the code more readable, I'd suggest taking these steps.

- Decompose your problem into a series of separate actions.
- Give these actions names.
- Define a function main in your module that calls functions named
  after the actions:

def main():
    do_setp1()
    do_step2()
    # etc
    return

- Separate you existing code into the functions that you're calling in
  main()
- As @flaschbier suggested, collect related, common parameters into dictionaries  to make passing the around easier to manage.
- Consider repeating these steps on your new functions, decomposing
  them into sub-functions.

Done well, you should be left with a file that's easier to look at, because the function definitions and their indented bodies break up the flow of text.

The code should be easier to reason about because you only need to  understand one function at a time, instead of the entire script.

Generally you want to keep all the code related to a particular task in a single module, unless there's more than say 500 lines.  But before moving  code into separate modules see if you can reduce the total lines of code by factoring repeated code into functions, or making your code more succinct: for example see if `for` loops can be replaced by list comprehensions.

Consider using code linting tools to help you make the code well-formatted.

So in summary: don't go against the grain of Python by hiding code in another
module and going down the `import_and_run` route.  Instead use good code organisation and Python's inherent good visual structure to make your code readable.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, seems like you still haven't grasped the concept of Python modules.

Well, modules in Python are the `.py` files. Each function, class or even variables in a `.py` file can be imported into another program.

Consider a (perhaps crazy) example like this `crazy.py`:

```
class crazyCl:
    # crazy stuffs
    pass

def crazyFn():
    # some another crazy stuffs

crazyVar = 'Please do not try this at home'
```

Now, to import any of these, into another program, say `goCrazy.py` in the same folder, simply do this

```
import crazy # see ma, no .py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print crazy.crazyVar # Please do not try this at home
```

This is a simple introduction to Python modules. There are many other features like packages that have to be tried out.

As a simple introduction, this should do. Hope you got some idea.